# Winrar command line zip folder

Tags: command-line, zip, winrar

I am trying to use WinRAR command line to zip folder:

```
"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip "e:\output.zip" "e:\foldertozip\"
```

If the `foldertozip` contains file, the command line works. But if the folder contain no file but folders where sub folder will contain files, it will appear the error saying `No files to add`.

How can I solve it?

Comment: It doesn't recognize `-afzip` flag for me.

Answer (score 9):

#### If the folder contains no files apart from subfolder containing files there is an error

Use the `-r` recurse subfolders switch.

---

#### Examples to compress a folder

> ```
> rar a -r yourfiles.rar *.txt c:\yourfolder
> ```
>
> creates archive yourfiles.rar and compresses all .txt files in
>   c:\yourfolder and all its subfolders
>
> ```
> rar a yourfiles
> ```
>
> creates archive yourfiles.rar and compresses all files in the current
>   folder, but doesn’t include subfolders (note lack of extension; WinRAR
>   will use the default extension .rar)
>
> - `a` command adds to the archive
> - `-r`  switch recurses subfolders

Source [Using the WinRAR Command-line tools in Windows](http://comptb.cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by removing `\` at the back.

```
"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afzip "e:\output.zip" "e:\foldertozip"
```

Comment: I too had to specify the location of WinRAR.exe. The other answer doesn't indicate that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this:
if the rar.exe file is in the program files folder
 c:\program files\winrar\rar a -r -df

Comment: Maybe be a bit more verbose and consider improving the formatting. What do those switches do? You could use ``` to mark something as differently. Right now it doesn't seem to be an improvement compared to the other answers?

Comment: Reportedly -df deletes files after archiving. See https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwitches.htm